# Is it right approach to implement LOGGER with support of Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()?

Tags: java, multithreading, logging

In order to avoid the too many LOGGER instance of each Class, I am trying to implement with the one common LOGGER instance by using Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() to get the class name and method name. Is it advisable to use Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() method in Java 1.8/1.9?

```
//My LoggerService Class
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LoggerService {
private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerService.class);

    static String getClazz() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[4].getClassName()+"::";
    }

    static String getMethod() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[4].getMethodName()+"::";
    }

   public static void info(Object message) {
        if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.info(getClazz() +getMethod()+ message);
        }
    }
}

//Usage
class LoggerTest{ 
   public void loggerTest(){
      LoggerService.info("my message");
   }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not advisable. Having several Logger instances is not an issue, and you're tryign to optimize something that doesn't need to be.

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() ` has performance cost.